# How do I assign a single value from SQLite (according to two other values) to my Python variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a simple online login form using Python and SQLite3:

```
user_email = request.forms.get("email")
user_password = request.forms.get("password")
connection = sqlite3.connect("/home/hassanrashid/mysite/users.db")
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT UserName from account WHERE UserEmail=? AND UserPassword=?", (user_email, user_password))
```

The email and password values entered into the html form are assigned to the `user_email` and `user_password` variables respectively. What I'm trying to do is, once the user logs in, he is greeted with a welcome message ("Welcome, UserName!").

My question is, how do I assign the `UserName` value from my SQLite database table to my Python variable `user_name`?

I've also tried this code:

```
user_name = c.execute("SELECT UserName from account WHERE UserEmail=?", (user_email)).fetchone()
```

But that gives me an error: `"Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 15 supplied."` There are 15 rows in my database. I'm assuming that the criteria (`WHERE UserEmail=?`) isn't being applied.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `(user_email)` doesn't create a tuple `(user_email,)` does. There are probably 15 characters in the email address and it's unpacking the string of characters into 15 individual characters.

Comment: @PeterWood, thank you, that seems to be working. However, now my welcome message is displaying: `Welcome, ('Name',)!` When I slice it using `user_name = user_name[2:6]`, it then becomes `Welcome, ()!` Just two brackets and nothing else, which is strange. How do I go about showing the user_name value without the brackets, quotes and commas?

Comment: @Hassan The (single element) row you are getting is a tuple still, so if you want the first (and only) element of that row, you'd use user_name[0]. Actually, you'll probably also want to error check, e.g. see if you did in fact get a result, and assign the appropriate value to your user_name.

Comment: @bgse I got it! I was getting a tuple, and I used the [0] to extract the value. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_name = c.execute("SELECT UserName from account WHERE UserEmail=?", (user_email)).fetchone()
```

Two issues with this:

1. `(user_email)` is not a tuple, so you are not passing a 1-element tuple to `execute()`. Instead, pass `(user_email,)` to make a 1-element tuple.
2. The return value of [`fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) will return the whole result row as a tuple. If there is only one column in the row, you will still get a 1-element tuple back. You need to unpack the tuple first in order to fix this:

```
query = "SELECT UserName from account WHERE UserEmail=?"
result = c.execute(query, (user_email,)) 

# either store the row tuple first
row = result.fetchone()
user_name = row[0]

# or you could unpack the tuple immediately (note the trailing comma)
user_name, = result.fetchone()
```